# C++ xml-rpc client with utf-8 support for windows

Tags: c++, windows, xml-rpc

Is there any XML-RPC client for windows for C++ with UTF-8 support?

I looked at XMLRPC++, but it doesn't support any encoding.

Comment: An XML library that doesn't support encoding?  That's special.  List: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC#C.2B.2B

Comment: The problem is that XMLRPC++ does its own xml parsing and unfortunately doesn't support any encoding other than default.
xmlrpc++ client for windows is an adaptation of xmlrpc++ for windows.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at gSoap.

http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.1

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons UTF-8 was created was to be transparent to most existing applications, and so will xmlrpc++ though I guess you get in trouble if you enable Unicode character set in the visual studio project.

If you feed xmlrpc++ UTF-8, it'll pass it through, same thing if you receive UTF-8. (And remember that all ascii characters encode as themselves in UTF-8)

Comment: I know what is xml and when it is used. 
The problem is not that xmlrpc++ can't passthough utf-8, but is that xmlrpc++ doesn't set or understand encoding of in/outbound xml-rpc request.
So the xml parser doesn't understand the document(request, actually) encoding.

Comment: Well, you asked about UTF-8, but yes - if you need encoding/decoding of charsets other than utf-8/ascii or your default charset , you won't get that with xmlrpc++.